# Sorting numbers in a 2d array in ascending order then presenting it in 1d

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

So my task is to take 20 numbers, put it in a 4 x 5 array, then sort them in ascending order then output it in a 1d array.
so far, my code just changes the 2d into 1d but can't sort it yet.

```
 #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 20;
    const int ROW = 4;
    const int COLUMN = 5;

    int numbers[ROW][COLUMN] = { 16, 22, 99, 4, 18, -254, 4, 101,
    5, 98, 105, 6, 15, 2, 45, 33, 88, 72, 16, 3 };

    int sort[SIZE] = {};

    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMN; j++)
        {
            sort[i] = numbers[i][j];
            cout << sort[i] << endl;
        }
    }

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: In this community you have to show what have you done.

Comment: "_my task is_" - you got that part right. How can we help? Show your effort by presenting a [mcve].

Comment: "sorting" a 2D array is ambiguous. Sort each row or each column? Can numbers move from one row/column to other rows/columns in the sorting.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example, why you should never use `using namespace std;`. You are using a variable with name `sort` and we want to use the `sort` function. So, please do never ever use `using namespace std;`

Next. You can use `std::sort` from the algorithm library. Since your C-Style array is stored as contiguous bytes in memory, we can access it through a pointer.

Please see:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    constexpr size_t SIZE = 20;
    constexpr size_t ROW = 4;
    constexpr size_t COLUMN = 5;

    int numbers[ROW][COLUMN] { 
        {16, 22, 99, 4, 18}, 
        {-254, 4, 101, 5, 98}, 
        {105, 6, 15, 2, 45}, 
        {33, 88, 72, 16, 3} 
    };

    int sort[SIZE];
    int *num = reinterpret_cast<int*>(numbers);
    std::sort(num, num+SIZE);

    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMN; j++)
        {
            sort[i] = numbers[i][j];
            std::cout << sort[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return (0);
}
```